# I want access the component snippet in nette framework

Tags: ajax, nette

I have using the template code like:

```
{snippetArea wrapper}
    {control addFormControl}
{/snippetArea}
```

and in `addFormControl` component code is like:

```
{snippet clientSnippet}
...... 
{/snippet}
```

I am using ajax with method presenter method:

```
public function handleClientChange(){
        $this['addFormControl']['addForm']['consignment_client']->setValue("test");

        $this->redrawControl('wrapper');
        $this->redrawControl('clientSnippet');
    }
```

But it is not redraw the snippet snippet id is `snippet-addFormControl-clientSnippet`. Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can call $this->redrawControl('clientSnippet'); in presenter and expect to redraw component. You should call this in the component.

Something like $this['addFormControl']->redrawControl('clientSnippet');

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do it. 
In my latest project i was doing something quite similiar, it's pretty simple tho.
For Nette I use this Ajax: https://github.com/vojtech-dobes/nette.ajax.js

.latte file:

```
<input type="text" id="search-car" data-url="{plink refreshCars!}">

{snippet carlist}
{foreach $cars as $car}
   {var $photo = $car->related('image')->fetch()}
   {if $photo}
     <img src="{plink Image:image $photo->filename}"/>
   {/if}
 </a>
{/foreach}
{/snippet}
```

Notice the '!' at the end of the text input. It's tells Nette to look after the handle function.

The presenter:

```
public function handleRefreshCars()
{
    $this->redrawControl('carlist');
}

public function renderDefault($foo = null)
{
    if ($foo === null || $foo === '') {
        $this->template->cars = array();
    } else {
        $this->template->cars = $this->carDao->getFiltered($foo);
    }
}
```

And JS:

```
function callFilterAjax(url, data) {
        $.nette.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data
     });
 }

$("#search-contract-car").on('load focus focusout change paste keyup', function () {
    callFilterAjax($(this).data('url'), {"foo": $(this).val()});
});
```

This should be it. I hope you find this useful